# User's Exchange 2010 emails disappearing

Tags: email, exchange-2010, outlook-2010, android

I've encountered a very strange user issue with regards to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010. Emails seem to be vanishing, it could be one or many at a time. It's very infrequent and has only been happening to one user in this company. 
For example, it was reported yesterday that an entire day's worth of emails disappeared shortly after it was viewed by the user. The account is linked to multiple devices. The company mainly works on a Terminal Server, but the issue has not occurred with any other user. 
Search-MailboxAuditLog has been used to track down any strange or deliberate activity of the specific user. 
Unfortunately that has not returned any usable information on the issue. The only thing that's seen around the times audited are "Partially Succeeded" Operation Results relating to MoveToDeletedItems initiated from an Android device. And those were not related to the ones that were missing as per the user. User's Outlook client has also been checked for Recover Deleted Items, Deleted Items Folder and any other folder the emails could have been moved to, but still none of the items were found. Honestly its very difficult to pinpoint a specific cause.
If anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated, and help me solving issues that could pop up in the future.
Exchange Server 2010, Version 14.03.0361.001 is being used along with Outlook 2010, Version 14.0.7181.5000(32 bit).

Thanks again

Comment: Does one of the remote device(s) get the email in a pop3 fashion ?

Comment: I don't think so. I have to check if there are any other devices I'm not aware of that the account could have been added on. But the mail command I mentioned above does not mention any more than 2 devices. If one does get the email in a pop 3 fashion, would the device not appear in the MailAuditLog that was run on the user account?